# matlab's imagesc background color

Tags: matlab, background-color

I'm using the newest version of matlab. I'm plotting a matrix using the imagesc command with the jet colormap. The background values of the matrix are zero and are plotted in the image as the lowest color on the color bar, which is dark blue. Is there a way to make the background zero values plot as white?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 j = jet;
 j(1,:) = [ 1 1 1 ];
 colormap(j);
 imagesc(Img);
```

Only thing is that anything else in the image that maps to the lowest color is going to also come out white.